# Knowing what objects to clusterExport beforehand

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm new to using the parallel packages and have started exploring them in a bid to speed up some of my work. An annoyance I often encounter is that the `foreach` command will throw up problems when I have not `clusterExport` the relevant functions/variables.

## Example

I know that the example below does not necessarily need `foreach` to make it fast, but for illustration sake, I'll use it.

```
library(doParallel)
library(parallel)
library(lubridate)
library(foreach)

cl <- makeCluster(c("localhost", "localhost", "localhost","localhost"), type = "SOCK")
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = 4)

Dates <- sample(c(dates = format(seq(ISOdate(2010,1,1), by='day', length=365), format='%d-%m-%Y')), 500, replace = TRUE)

foreach(i = seq_along(Dates), .combine = rbind) %dopar% dmy(Dates[i])

Error in dmy(Dates[i]) : task 1 failed - "could not find function "dmy""
```

As you can see, there is an error that says that the `dmy` function is not found. I then have to go on and add the following:

```
clusterExport(cl, c("dmy"))
```

So my question is, besides looking at the error for clues on what to export, is there a more elegant way of knowing beforehand what objects to export or is there a way to share the global environment with all the slaves before running the `foreach`?

Comment: There's a `.packages` argument for that.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? I tried (.packages()) and it listed the packages attached. But how do I export all objects of a package? I tried clusterExport(cl, c("library(lubridate)")) and clusterExport(cl, c("lubridate")) to no avail

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `.packages` argument to `foreach`, not the `.packages` function.

Comment: oh ok. I understand now. Would you want to put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to export individual package functions manually like that.  You can use the `.packages` argument to the `foreach` function to load the required packages, so all package functions will be available to your `%dopar%` expression.

Comment: Does this work for the new parallel library in 2.14.0, e.g. parLapply? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @mindless.panda: You should be able to use `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(packageName))` to load packages on each cluster node.

Comment: Thanks, I also just placed a `library(packagename)` within the anonymous function in the parLapply.